# Cant Send picture message(mms)from one emulator to another in Android

Tags: android

Can anybody know how to send mms between two emulators? It sends sms successfully but not mms with picture.

Thanks in advance

I have send mms programatically and user offer send button by OS but it shows sending...

I have successfully send sms messages on two emulators with 5554 and 5556 but for mms with picture after click on send button it shows "sending..."

```
String imagePath="test.jpeg";
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        //    sendIntent.setClassName("com.android.mms", "com.android.mms.ui.ComposeMessageActivity");
            sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", "I Send you pic.");
            sendIntent.putExtra("address", phoneNumber);
            sendIntent.setType("image/png");
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(dataFile));
   //         context.startActivityForResult(sendIntent, 1);
            context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Send"));
```

Comment: Why down vote? It is valid question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Android SDK Release Notes(http://developer.android.com/sdk/RELEASENOTES.html)

It is not possible to send MMS messages between emulator instances.